# SQL Server local instance that transparently points to remote server? Like a named instance remote proxy

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a purchased commercial app that accesses a named, locally installed SQL server instance.

Is there any way for us to ***transparently*** move the DB to a remote shared SQL Server host, but still have things configured within SQL Server so that the local software can access as it it were a local instance?

Keep in mind, since it's a purchased software package, I don't have the ability to modify the queries it's running, so if tables have to change into fully qualified, or other special T-SQL syntax to make this work, it's not an option.

Effectively, we need to "trick" the app to use a remote database, but    access as if it's a local instance (though configuration, some sort of proxy, or perhaps dark magic).

The total extent of the application DB configuration settings is to select the name of the local instance to connect, as shown in this image: [image].

SQL server is installed on the local machine (Win2012R2x64), and has a couple instances running.  I have complete control of both local & remote SQL servers, so can make unrestricted config changes to them.  Current DB version is SQL2014, but could upgrade to newer if newer version features are needed to do this.

Comment: I'm guessing no, but am interested to see trickery that people can come up with. I have to ask though, **why**?

Comment: Have you tried creating a local instance (same DB name) with views (to remote server) that have names replicating the table structure in the remote server?

Comment: I imagine the app is probably using named pipes to access the local db server, but if it will fall back to using a tcp/ip connection, you could try a simple port-forwarding utility - tcp forwarding rather than MSSQL forwarding. SSH will do it in a pinch, but there are no doubt simpler options.

Comment: In fact, even if the app refuses to connect over tcp, it should be fairly trivial to make a custom forwarder that listens on the mssql named pipe and forwards the data to a remote tcp socket. As long as mssql uses the same flavor of TDS for local and remote communication, that should work.

Comment: @Harun, it appears to be using a shared memory connection so I don't think that would work in my case

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating an alias to the remote sqlserver from the local sql server. (Via Sql Server Configuration Manager | Aliases | Add a new Alias name)

Your local instance alias should be the name server name that the connection string is using to connect.

I've used this method in the past to change the sql instance that I was connecting to without changing any connection string info.

More info [here](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/02/09/how-to-configure-a-sql-server-alias-for-a-named-instance-on-a-development-machine)

Comment: I think this might be the right path, but I've hit an issue  I created the SQLServer alias (both x32 & x64), but the alias doesn't seem to get advertised when listing local instances.  In mgmt studio, I can connect to the alias, but when using the app, the alias isn't listed as an available option.  Also, when I go to "Browse for servers -> Local Server", only the real instances are shown, but not the alias that I created.  Thoughts?

Comment: Other notes:  [1] the app seems to connect via shared memory protocol, [2] the app only seems to accept (or display connection options) to instances visible to the browse for servers/Local servers.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what sort of access the commercial app needs in the locally installed database once the app has set up and created its database.

You will probably invalidate any support agreements in the attempt.  Worse still, if a commercial app insists on a local instance then I dread to think what security horrors it will insist upon in your shared instance.

You need to profile the database while the functionality of the application is used to find out what it does and how it does it.  Even if you determine that the security permissions could be greatly restricted you may find that the app checks to see if it has a higher permission level.

I've no way to hand of testing this approach but....

- Install the app as usual which will be on your local instance
- Back up the DB on your local instance and restore the DB to your remote instance.  Remember to set up what logins are necessary.
- Set up a linked server to on your local instance to your remote instance.
- Delete all objects in your local DB instance
- Create sysnonyms for all objects pointing at the remote instance.

If it is an application that simply requires direct table access this might work.  It is however an **ABOMINATION**.

Comment: Agreed, this setup would be an ABOMINATION.  I don't know the inner workings with linked & synonyms, but when using DB object synonyms does that actually push queries to the remote engine and only return result set, or simply cause the local instance to unload all the data from tables and bring locally so it could do joins, etc. locally?  I figured it'd do something like when MS Access users naively setup linked tables to ODBC sources and try to join a small table in MDB to remote table (and, of course, it never ends well!)